# Esqueleto `selectDistinct` not working

Tags: postgresql, haskell, yesod, esqueleto

`selectDistinct` seems to not be working for me, it's probably a simple error.
the query:

```
 info <- runDB $ 
        E.selectDistinct $ 
        E.from $ \(tp `E.InnerJoin` rnd `E.InnerJoin` h) -> do
        E.on (rnd E.^. RoundId E.==. h E.^. HoleRound)
        E.on (tp E.^. TpartTournament E.==. rnd E.^. RoundTourn)
        E.where_ ((tp E.^. TpartTournament E.==. E.val tId ))
        E.orderBy [E.asc (tp E.^. TpartId)]
        return (tp, rnd, h)
```

I'm quite sure that this represents the sql query which works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tpart.id, round.name, hole.hole_num, hole.score
from tpart
inner join round on round.tourn = tpart.tournament
inner join hole on hole.round = round.id
where tpart.tournament = 1;
```

To view the results I have a test handler to just print the result table.  Notice that for tpart 1, round 1, there are multiple hole 1 and hole 2.  In postgresql `SELECT DISTINICT` removed these duplicates.

```
     TpartId, RoundName, holeNum, HoleScore

Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 1, 1, 6
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 1, 2, 4
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 1, 1, 6
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 1, 2, 4
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 1, 1, 6
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 1, 2, 4
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 2, 1, 3
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 2, 2, 5
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 2, 1, 3
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 2, 2, 5
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 2, 1, 3
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 1}, round 2, 2, 5
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 1, 1, 6
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 1, 2, 4
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 1, 1, 6
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 1, 2, 4
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 1, 1, 6
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 1, 2, 4
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 2, 1, 3
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 2, 2, 5
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 2, 1, 3
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 2, 2, 5
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 2, 1, 3
Key {unKey = PersistInt64 3}, round 2, 2, 5
```

Sorry for the illegibility. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: to get closer to discovering your problem turn on query logging as mentioned at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-1.3.4.2/docs/Database-Esqueleto-Internal-Sql.html#v:toRawSql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that for a certain Hole, the hole's `round` AND the Hole's `part` must equal they're respective parts. Also, the inner join was redundant in that situation.